# What does 'has_3([1, 3, 3])' mean in Python?

Tags: python

I understand List use square brackets, but what does it mean when [] is inside a ()?

Would be great if someone could clarify for me. Thanks!

Comment: Is `has_3` a function?

Comment: ```has_3()``` is a function. ```[1, 3, 3]``` is the input of that function.

Comment: Yes, it is a function. I do apologize for not stating clearly as I'm still trying to wrap my head around, well basically everything. But thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a passing of `[1, 3, 3]` list to whatever `has_3` is (could be any callable - function, class, lambda) as a first argument.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this case has_3() is a user-defined function that accepts a list as an argument.

```
def has_3(input_list):
''' 
    :param: input_list 
    :return something (may a boolean (True/False) whether input_list has 3 or not )
'''

    return <something>
```

But again, we will not get to know unless we look at the code. This is like the best guess.

Comment: This would be my guess. with ```return 3 in input_list```

Comment: or ```return len(input_list) == 3```. Like you say, no way of knowing. but seems sensible it's a function.